SearchKit + alter default query for add 'AND' behavior
by default, the default searchKit query seems to use a 'OR' behavior (multi_match). Is there a solution to alter the default query for add an operator 'AND' ?
I tried to use a query_rules without sucess...
Thanks for your help.
